# Can we pass array values using post method

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have an array in which I have some values like

```
$errors[]="Invalid username";
$errors[]="Invalid pass word";
```

and there is a jquery function to load the page. Can we pass this array through this jquery function?

```
$("#menu_div2").load("<?=ROOT_PATH?>ajax/div_openreviewpages.php?error=<?=$errors?>");
```

When i try to do this, I get an error on div_openreviewpages.php. It shows as array variable but when i try to do foreach on this array it is showing invalid argument supplied.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sends only word `Array`

You can do

```
$("#menu_div2").load("<?=ROOT_PATH?>ajax/div_openreviewpages.php?error=<?=json_encode($errors)?>");
```

And in div_openreviewpages.php do

```
$error=json_decode($_GET['error']);
foreach($error as $err){
echo$err;
}
```

Comment: json_encode outputs with additional quotes,so my jquery execution gets dropped

Comment: You can mask quotes with `addslashes` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php

Comment: no i was asking about additional quotes,and because of these quotes my jquery execution is getting dropped

Answer (score 1):

try sending them through params, instead of passing in the url itself, like :-

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#result').load('test.php', { 'params[]': ["", ""] });
});

and retrieve them as post params, at the url side.

Comment: pls,can you explain with an example